# How to modify find/replace VBA code to assign a different parameter to each row according to row number?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to achieve a code which searches the row for a value and replaces the stated value with a value from the same row stated in another column.

So far I am stuck at this code. It searches for the stated "Findtext" from the entire column and replaces it with the first value from the stated column. When the loop moves to the next row, the "Findtext" value has already been replaced and therefore the value I want from row 2 is no longer assigned.

```
Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Dim x As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Numrows = Sheet1.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 1 To Numrows

    Findtext = "Sheet2!$A$1"
    Replacetext = Cells(x, 2)

    Cells.replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Next x
```

The end goal is for the code to search for the "Findtext" from the first row, replace it with the "Replacetext" from the first row of another column and then move on to the next row and repeat the action until all rows have been looked through and replaced with the respective values from the other column.

The application is in banking (replacing a static variable occurring in many columns/formulae with dynamic/point-in-time variables for each period for scenario analysis).

Comment: Instead of `Cells.replace` try with `Rows(x).Replace`